# Get email address of a 'person or group' field in dataform webpart using XSLT

Tags: email, xslt, person

I am trying to retrieve the email address of a person or group field. I have tried the expression:

```
value-of select= 'substring-before(substring-after(@person, concat("sip=",$dvt_apos)), $dvt_apos)' disable-output-escaping="no"
```

but it **returns nothing**, can someone help.

*Thanks*